# В чем отличие Windows Forms Application C++ и C#

Tags: c#, c++

В чем отличие Windows Forms Application C++ и C#

Создаю два одинаковых проекта

Visual C++ - CLR - Windows Forms Application

и

Visual C# - Windows - Windows Forms Application

Исходный файл в C++ получается 48 кб

В C# всего 8 кб

**Вопрос**

Используют ли оба проекта Microsoft .NET Framework

или проект на C++ это как в Delphi без технологии .NET

???

и почему разный размер исполняемого файла получился?
ведь внутри идентичный код

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/75188/c-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81

Comment: Ничего что "c++ vs c#" и "winforms c++ vs winforms c#" это немного разные вопросы?

Comment: Ну вообще нет,оба работают с Framework,а почему вес так отличается незнаю)

Comment: Мой вам совет: не пытайтесь писать на C++/CLI, пользуйтесь каноничным C#, как завещал великий Хейльсберг.

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj, а Вы точно об исходном коде (буковки набитые Вами), говорите?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

c++/cli использует .net. А просто с++ (win32, win, native и другие префиксы/суффиксы) - нет.

Почему размер разный - нужно смотреть декомпилятором внутрь. Там будет понятно. Возьмите ildasm (встроенный, стандартный) или бесплатный [dotpeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) от jetbrains + [ссылка на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119153/). Посмотрите внутрь своих проектов и сравните.

> Используют ли оба проекта Microsoft .NET Framework

да

> и почему разный размер исполняемого файла получился?

C# это самый родной язык для .net. Все что нужно, уже есть внутри фреймворка. Если чего то нет - проще добавить в фреймворк. Не даром ведь он сотни мегабайт.

C++/CLI - Это костыль. и приходиться делать "переходники". (хотя их можно было бы тоже запихать в фреймворк). Все таки философия с++ немножко перпендикулярна C# и .NET. И Майкрософт создала новый искусственный язык, который и не C++ и не C#.

> ведь внутри идентичный код

нет. Он может и выполняет одно и тоже, но код разный.

Answer (score 4):

При компиляции C++/CLI проекта в сборку инлайнится [куча сервисного кода](http://pastebin.com/Li198BSy).
В случае с C# такого "лишнего" кода совсем немного:

```
get_Default         
.ctor               
.cctor              
Dispose             
InitializeComponent 
sub_C0              
sub_F0              
get_ResourceManager 
get_Culture         
set_Culture         
Main
```

(обе сборки скомпилированы из пустых проектов WindowsFormsApplication)